# Why restoring a partial backup is overwriting my whole Google Cloud database?

Tags: backup, google-cloud-platform, database, restore, overwrite

I have two projects in Firebase/Google Cloud, one for Development and another for Production (where the app is live).

**Steps I took**

1. I exported a specific collection from the database of my Production project (i.e. game/latest/buildings).
2. I copied that to my Development project (trasferred data between newly created buckets in both projects).
3. I imported the backup into the database of my Development project.

**What I expected: **
The data of the buildings in my development project (newer data) has been overwritten by the data of the buildings in the backup (older data), while the rest of the data has been left intact.

**What really happened:**
The whole database of my Development project was overwritten. Somehow, in addition to the buildings' data, the rest of the files had been reverted to an older version.

May that be because I did something wrong?

Thanks in advance and have a great day! :)

Comment: Typically a database restore drops the database or table as the first action. You have not provided details on the backup or restore method you are using. Some backups are just SQL commands in a file. Look at the backup file to see if that applies to your situation.